# Only Get A Certain Number of Posts From WP_Query

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. None of my WP_Queries are returning the given number of posts. From what I can tell, it's returning all of them. How do I fix this? Here is the code I'm currently using for my loops:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php $review = new WP_Query(array(
    "posts_per_page" => 1,
    "category_name" => "reviews",
    'nopaging' => true
)); ?>
<?php if($review->have_posts()): while($review->have_posts()): $review->the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Everything here works as expected -->
    <?php break; ?> <!-- I have to break the loop by force, which is bad -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <!-- Placeholder content goes here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nopaging=true` override `posts_per_page` and sets it to `-1` which will return all posts. Remove that and you should be fine